# How to insert a white space into a string in php?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to separate a string with a whitespaces based on the pattern I want. In every two words and sometimes three. For example:

```
$string = 'marketplace';
```

become

```
$string = 'mark et pl ace';
```

I know that `preg_replace` can do this but I don't know the pattern. Can anybody tell me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: is it fix to two characters?

Comment: `$string = implode(' ', str_split($string, 2));`

Comment: @Abaji, then billyonecan's anser is perfect for your need!

Comment: I think that right selection depends on rule where do you want to insert that whitespaces. If it's "dumb" (insert whitespace each 2 characters), you don't have to use regular expression.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy, that's give me another idea, so I edit my question. thanks.

Comment: @Abaij The pattern is description of a rule. So the most important thing to create the pattern is to know the rule. "*every two words and sometimes three*" is not very exact rule :)

Comment: @DawidFerenczy, just updated the question to make it a rule :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use preg_replace...., however @billyonecan's str_split is probably a better way.

```
preg_replace('/(..)/','$1 ', $string);
```

Comment: And maybe `trim(...)` for the last space.

Comment: Per OP requirement this should be accepted. Nevertheless, @vlzvl answer is correct too.

Comment: And if you want to do it every 'n' then: `/(.{n})/` eg: `/(.{3})/` also if the original string is an exact multiple of 'n' in length as Joop points out you probably want to rtrim() the result.

Comment: @Yorick, it's working. But what if I want to separate the first 3 characters and the next is 2?

Comment: @Abaij if you are looking for something like "MarketingStuff" => "Mar ke tin gS tuf f", ie: 3 characters then two characters etc you would use something like `/(.{3})(.{2})/` with a replacement pattern of '$1 $2 '. That said, if you always want the same length of split throughout the string but different for different strings see my comment above. If you are varying the length within the string and especially if it is not in a repeating manner you may want to resort to a different approach.

Answer (score 4):

this?

```
$string = 'market';
echo implode(" ",str_split($string,2));
```

Comment: your answer is the same to @billyonecan

Comment: indeed, just saw the comment.

Comment: @John Robertson, just saw the comment after wrote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should work with `preg_replace`:

```
$result = preg_replace("/(\\w{2})/uim", "$1 ", $string);
```

example:

http://regex101.com/r/hZ0xA1/1

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
implode(" ",str_split($string, 2))
```

Here the important code is

```
<?php
$string = "market";
echo implode(" ",str_split($string, 2));
?>
```

`str_split` converts the `$string` to an array which contents packs of 2 characters.

then `implode` will join the arrays with spaces b/w all array values.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function. Just decide in which steps the spaces should be placed.

```
function split_by_position($string, $position){
    $splitted = str_split($string, $position);

    foreach($splitted as $part){
        $result .= $part.' ';
    }
    echo $result;
}

$string = 'market';
echo split_by_position($string, 2);
```

billyonecan's solution really looks better and for sure shorter. I suggest you to use his one. ^^